# Books on stochastic prediction theory

Tags: statistics, reference-request, book-recommendation

I am reading the papers of [Wiener and Masani](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF02404472) on stochastic prediction theory. I do not have a statistics background, but for some reason I need to know this subject. My questions are:

1. Can someone please suggest a modern text book which deals these topics, if possible, up to present day work.
2. Also please suggest some book where this topic has been discussed as it was developed historically.

I know decent amount of measure theoretic probability (following Kai Lai Chung), and work on operator theory, and know vary basic stochastic theory. Advanced thanks for any help/ suggestions, and etc..